# How to make two sidekiq workers in parallel?

Tags: sql-server, redis, parallel-processing, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

So I am using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.5 version (Mssql database) and I created two sidekiq worker and call the sidekiq worker in the controller by "perform_async" method . What I am required is to make this two workers to work in parallel . But currently one worker is working . How can I make this two workers to work parallel ?

Answer (score -1):

In development mode, Rails limits Sidekiq to one job at a time. In production mode, Rails turns on eager loading which allows parallel jobs.

Comment: Switched the mode from development to production , but still one worker is working .